# One decimal field taking up 75% file size of power bi file

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have a Power bi file which is over a 2gb in size and found one field is taking up 1.5gb of the file size.  When I change it to a whole number or decimal it is reduced to 350mb.

I wanted to change to a decimal but I feel it being changed to a decimal place shouldn't increase the file size so dramatically.  Is this correct and wanted to check if this is expected behaviour

Thanks for any help

Here is a screenshot of the settings:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with only preserving 4 decimals then you can switch to a “fixed decimal number” data type and it should compress the same as a whole number. Fixed decimal is stored as an integer and the last 4 digits are interpreted to be right of the decimal as explained [here](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/understanding-numeric-data-type-conversions-in-dax/).